# How to trigger a AWS lambda by sending event to EventBridge

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I have a AWS lambda that the trigger for activating it is an event from EventBridge (rule)

The rule looks like this:

```json
{
  "detail-type": ["ECS Task State Change"],
  "source": ["aws.ecs"],
  "detail": {
    "stopCode": ["EssentialContainerExited", "UserInitiated"],
    "clusterArn": ["arn:aws:ecs:.........."],
    "containers": {
      "name": ["some name"]
    },
    "lastStatus": ["DEACTIVATING"],
    "desiredStatus": ["STOPPED"]
  }
}
```

This event is normally triggered when ECS task status is changed (in this case when a task is killed)

My questions are:

1. Can I simulate this event from command line?
   maybe by running `aws events put-events --entries file://putevents.json`
   (What should I write in the putevents.json file?)
2. Can I simulate this event from Javascript code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** Yes and yes, provided you deal with with the limitation that user-generated events cannot have a `source` that begins with `aws`.

---

Send custom events to EventBridge with the [PutEvents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-putevents.html) API. The API is available in the CLI as well as in the SDKs (see [AWS JS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-eventbridge/classes/puteventscommand.html)). The list of custom events you pass in the `entries` parameter [must have](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-events.html#eb-custom-event) three fields at a minimum:

```json
[
  {
    "source": "my-custom-event", // cannot start with aws !!,
    "detail-type": "ECS Task State Change",
    "detail": {}  // copy from the ECS sample events docs
  }
]
```

The ECS [task state change event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_cwe_events.html#ecs_task_events) samples in the ECS documentation make handy templates for your custom events. You can safely prune any non-required field that you don't need for pattern matching.

Custom events are not permitted to mimic the `aws` system event sources. So amend your rule to also match on your custom source name:

```json
"source": ["aws.ecs", "my-custom-event"],
```